# Regex for a non-fixed pattern

Tags: files, regular-expression

I am trying to come up with the right regex (compatible with python) that would match a file that contained sample input as follows:

```
On the third day of Christmas
 my true love sent to me:
 three worms a eating
 two garlic cloves
 and a koala in a bamboo spree
```

This is just ONE possibility. The important part is that the first line have "On the X day of Christmas"  with no wrong capitalization (like ChrISTmas).

That should be something like

```
\^On the [first|second|third|fourth]...
```

all the way up to twelfth. 
Same thing with the ending, *last line* just needs to have 'and a ...'

```
 $and a *\         (?)
```

**But how can I check with regex that each line of the file is in the correct order**?

For example, 'two garlic...' before 'three worms' is NOT correct

```
 On the third day of Christmas
 my true love sent to me:
 two garlic cloves         #SWITCHED
 three worms a eating
 and a koala in a bamboo spree
```

Similarly, it can't jump bits. If it starts with 'five X', the next line needs to be 'four Y', 'three', 'two', etc.

```
 On the third day of Christmas
 my true love sent to me:
 five cats a dancing       #Goes from 'five cats' to 'two garlic', not ok
 two garlic cloves
 and a koala in a bamboo spree
```

Here are some attempts at matching multi-line regex I came up with, but to no avail. http://www.codeshare.io/jLI9l

Here's another one where I removed the file-input and tried something else: http://www.codeshare.io/u4E7t

I want it to be able to match and print 'correct' if the input file structure/match is correct

Comment: So the correct versions are stored somewhere already? If so, once you match, `diff` the results. http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html Note the example at the very bottom.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Is there a relation of the word "third" in line 1 to the word "three" in line three? Is a sequence of lines containing, e.g., "eighth", "...", "four", "two", "and a", a valid match, or is the possible word set in the last three lines generally only from the words "three", "two", "and a"?

Comment: @Janis sorry, to be more clear, the input file only is seen as a 'correct' file if it starts off with On the X day of Christmas (^On the [first|second| etc.) and then if the LAST of the file begins with 'and a'. I'm having a hard time with python checking multiline regex and printing a match for that.

Comment: Here is a test I did, which did not print out the match: http://www.codeshare.io/jLI9l

Comment: So far it was clear; I got confused (and still am) by your requirement "if lines 2 and 3 were switched [...]" implies "incorrect".

Comment: This was another attempt from scratch, trying to see if I can match across newlines but no luck. http://www.codeshare.io/u4E7t

Comment: What I mean by that is, if in the original input at the top of the page, let's say the 3rd and 4th lines were inverted, it wouldn't be right since the sequence would not be in the right order.  (two garlic cloves followed by three worms a eating)

Comment: If it's only the "set of possible strings" in certain positions what's unclear, then in most regexp parsers (not sure about python, though) it's formulated as (something like) `/^On the (first|second|third|fourth)/`; the two slashes may be unnecessary, and in some parsers the parenthesis (and occasionally the pipe as well) need escaping by a backslash.

Comment: Okay, so again my question; would "five garlic cloves followed by two worms" be correct? - Please extend the question to make all that clear; it's not so good to spam the comments section by such clarification ping-pong.

Comment: @Janis, that would not be correct unless it was five cloves, four trains, three X, two y etc. It can't jump numbers, very good point, hadn't thought of it. I'll clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a regex is really not the best way to go here, since you need to have some kind of memory to remember the previous number in the first word, for every new line you test.

I'm not saying it can't be done (you have a finite set of numbers, so you could technically enumerate every possible file combination "by hand" with a, very nasty, multi-line regex), what I'm saying is: why using it in the first place, when you can actually write Python code to do it (waaaay faster) ? You could have something like a sorted list of all numbers `["one", ..., "twelve"]` and days `["first", ..., "twelfth"]`, then split your file (as a big `str`) by lines (making it a list of `str`s) and then test the lines in a `for` loop using indices in these lists ?